# Why is `this` bound to the global context?

Tags: javascript, promise, this

Why does the following snippet return `true` and `undefined`?

```
var fns = {
  foo() {
    console.log(this === window); // true (instead of false)
    console.log(typeof this.bar); // undefined (instead of function)
  },
  bar() {},
};

Promise.resolve().then(fns.foo);
```

(If I run `fns.foo();` instead of `Promise.resolve().then(fns.foo);` it prints `false` and `function` as expected)

Is it a promise specific definition?

I checked

- [MDN - this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) but found no reason for this behavior.
- the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-this-keyword) but did not understand it.

Comment: It isn't *bound* that's the issue. The value of `this` is determined *at the time of calling the function*. When we talk about "bound context" then it's determined once and calling the function will not change it.

Comment: Also relevant: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Related to the issue though; `Promise.resolve().then(_ => fns.foo());`

Comment: The value of this is less complicated than it looks. In general you just have to ask one question: Who is the caller? In fns.foo() the caller is fns. In ..then(fns.foo), the caller is not fns. Then that's when things may become a bit more complicated, whether you are in strict mode or not, or if the function has already a value of this bound to it.

Comment: "In ..then(fns.foo), the caller is not fns" <- This is what I misunderstood. It's much clearer now. Thank you!